# A functional "composition" of homotopies is also a homotopy.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $h,h':X\to Y$ be homotopic and $k,k':Y\to Z$ be homotopic. The idea is to show that $k\circ h$ and $k'\circ h'$ are homotopic.

Let $F$ be a homotopy between $h(x)$ and $h'(x)$ and $G$ a homotopy between $k(x)$ and $k'(x)$. Define $H:X\times[0,1]\to Z$ by $G(F(x,t),t)$. Then $H$ is continuous as a composition of continuous maps and  for $x\in X$ we have 
\begin{align}
H(x,0)&=G(F(x,0),0) = G(h(x),0) = k\circ h(x)\\ H(x,1) &= G(F(x,1),1) = G(h(x),1) = k'\circ h'(x),
\end{align}
so $H$ is a homotopy between $k\circ h$ and $k'\circ h'$.

My question is this: We cannot exactly compose $F$ and $G$, since both are functions of two inputs, and one output, but instead we compose $G\circ (F, t\mapsto t)$. It turns out that this is correct, but how did we know a priori to choose $t\mapsto t$? Why not, e.g. $t\mapsto t^2$? This turns out to be a homotopy as well, since
\begin{align}
G(F(x,0),0^2) = G(F(x,0),0) = k\circ h(x)\\
G(F(x,1),1^2) = G(F(x,1),1) = k'\circ h'(x).
\end{align}
But clearly $t\mapsto 1-t$ would not work. Is it the case that we can choose any continuous $\alpha : [0,1]\to[0,1]$ with $\alpha(0)=0$ and $\alpha(1)=1$ and $G\circ(F,\alpha)$ would be a homotopy?

Comment: If you need a function from a set to itself, then the identity will usually be the first one you'll try, because it is so simple, always exists, and typically has the properties you want to have. And if it works, why not use it?

Comment: @celtschk True, the identity is the logical candidate, but I am still interested in whether an arbitrary continuous $\alpha:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with $\alpha(0)=0$ and $\alpha(1)=1$ would make $G\circ(F,\alpha)$ a homotopy.

Comment: Not only does it work, but the homotopies are homotopic to each other regardless of what you choose.

Comment: @ConnorMalin That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a homotopy $H : A \times I \to B$ and $t \in I = [0,1]$ define $H_t : A  \to B, H_t(a) = H(a,t)$.

Now let us denote your homotopy by $G * F$. This is certainly the most obvious solution because $(G * F)_t = G_t \circ F_t$, i.e. the homotopy $G * F$ is obtained by composing $G$ and $F$ *levelwise*.

Now let $\alpha, \beta : I \to I$ be continuous maps such that $\alpha(0) = \beta(0) = 0$ and $\alpha(1) = \beta(1) = 1$. Then $F^\alpha = F \circ (id_X \times \alpha)$ and $G^\beta = G \circ (id_Y \times \beta)$ are also homotopies between $h,h'$ and $k,k'$, respectively. Therefore also $G^\beta * F^\alpha$ is a homotopy as desired. But it definitely has no benefit to invoke $\alpha, \beta$ as additional ingredients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So in other words $H(x,t) = G(F(x,\alpha(t)), \beta(t))$ is also a homotopy when $\alpha,\beta$ are continuous maps that fix $0$ and $1$, and in particular so is $F^\alpha(x,t) = F(x,\alpha(t))$?

Comment: Yes, that is true.